# Why does "1" equal "+1"?

Tags: php

In PHP, the string "1" equals the string "+1" unless you do a strict comparison (===).

```
echo ("1" == "+1") ? "equals" : "not equals";  // result: "equals"
```

I'd prefer not to do a strict comparison, because the string "1" might be provided as an integer 1 in this case. I cannot do `intval()` to distinguish them because both return as 1, and I cannot do `is_numeric()` to distinguish them because both return true.

So, two questions please:

1. Is there any way to differentiate between these other than to convert the input to strings via `strval()` and use strict comparison?
2. Is this a bug or intended behavior in PHP? The reason doesn't seem mathematical ("2" does not equal "1+1" for instance, although "2" does equal "+2"). I'm curious as to the reasoning behind this.

Comment: Seems a bit contradictory what you want… :) You *want* loose comparison but not quite *as loose* as PHP defaults to…?

Comment: What about a pragmatic `((string)"1" === "+1")` or `((string) intval("1") === "+1")`?

Comment: "If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. " - [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Mathematically, one and positive one are equivalent, that's basically what you're seeing. I'm not sure why you would prefer to not do a strict comparison here.

Comment: I tried this example: http://ideone.com/ZHnJN4, it checks if the latter value is not a string (i.e., a numeric variable) in the comparison.

Comment: @arkascha, I don't believe so given the second question which mistakenly assumes the reason is not mathematical

Comment: @nickb, thank you, that's what I was missing. I didn't see how "+1" could be considered a number unless it was mathematical (PHP treating it like "0+1"), but of course, it's positive one. I wish I had thought of that.

Comment: *"although "2" does equal "+2""* – now I'm confused about what you were confused about… :-|

Comment: @deceze I did want loose comparison. I just forgot that + can indicate positivity in a number. I thought "+1" was no more a number than "%1" or "@1" or "&1" are. Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `==` instead of `===` a loose comparison is used.

This often leads to types using truthyness when comparing incomparable types

have a look a the manual here to see the table of comparison
http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

even though `"+1"` is not mentioned, it would be handled similarly to a `'-1'`

If you don't want this to happen, you do need to use `===`